# How can I get SIZE CHART using Amazon Products API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, marketplace

I have went through both the amazon products API documentations [Amazon Products Advertising API (AWS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/Welcome.html) and [Amazon Products API (MWS)](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/136-2739732-5876420?ie=UTF8&group=products&section=products&version=latest), but was unable to find size chart (Attaching Image for reference).

[image]

Please provide me the feasible solution to fetch the size chart through Amazon API.

Answer (score 0):

[http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/apparel/en_US/html/sizechart/womens.*V154091249*.html](http://z-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/apparel/en_US/html/sizechart/womens._V154091249_.html)

This url has the general size chart.

Comment: Thanks, but I need specific size chart for a product that too extract able and through API as I have to update it my system.
Also, the above link containing general size charts does not contain the one mentioned in screenshot. So, I think Amazon would have provision to get that specific size chart the seller has uploaded at the time of adding his/her listing.